# 'net' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to connect to a network drive,
I have written below code.
But I am fetching `'net' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

```
import copy,random, unicodedata, re, os
import subprocess, netrc

password  = "MyPWD"
domain_name = "MyDomain"
user_name = "MyName"
subprocess.call(r'net use m: /del', shell=True)
os.system(r"NET USE m: \\fileshare\\Users\\Dir %s /USER:%s\%s" % (password, domain_name, user_name))
```

Comment: You may be falling victim to 64-bit Windows' file system redirector. Try  `%windir%\Sysnative\net` instead of just `net`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue. @kindall 's comment got me on the right track to resolve this, but for me the path is `%windir%\SysWOW64\net`

Answer (score 1):

To add to the above, although I was able to use the `net` command using `%windir%\SysWOW64\net start` on the cmd prompt, adding `%windir%\SysWOW64\net` to the system PATH did ***not*** allow me to run `net start`.

To be able to run `net start`, make sure `C:\Windows\System32` is [added](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/net-view-command-not-working/76a32f13-1f06-46a3-ad8b-ff809f809bf8) to your system environment variables PATH.